# C++ Template performance inclusion model and inline model

Tags: c++, templates, generics, include

If I have a C++ template I have two choices (without the **export** keyword) to link them:

- Inclusion model with inlining - i.e. including the definitions together with the declarations in the .h file. This inlines all the functions and create a big unit (although it's lazy)
- Inclusion model without inlining - i.e. something like including this .h file:

code:

```
// templateinstantiations.cpp
#include "array.cpp"
template class array <int, 50>; // explicit instantiation
```

every time I want to use a template, and being careful to explicit instantiating every single type I need (this can be boring and hard to maintain)

My question is: I know that excessively inlining functions may cause memory thrashing and losses of performances.. besides it seems that in both the above cases compilation times are huge.. what is the tradeoff between the first and the second approach? Is there a criterion to choose the first over the second or I just need to try them out and "time" them?

Comment: Ehm... just do it the normal way and worry about improving compile times when they actually suffer from that? Just so you know, your templates probably won't cause any slowdown. Most of the stdlib is templates and they all just include the definitions in the headers.

Comment: Re: "(this can be boring and hard to maintain)" - indeed. Don't do it unless you can measure a **significant** benefit. In almost all cases, just don't do it.

Comment: I'm much more worried about potential "memory thrashing" phenomenons rather than "huge compilation times", I kind of "fear" the inline approach

Comment: It's actually up to the compiler to decide whether to inline code. It can also output code marked appropiately so the linker only includes one copy of it. Basically, I decided to leave the compiler-jobs to the people at Microsoft or the appropiate groups doing the gcc and clang compilers, rather than trying to do this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't really about templates but about inlining, I think. For the purposes of run-time performance, the compiler probably does the right choice in most cases: if it can see that a function is too big to benefit from inlining it is likely to generate a non-inlined version of any inline function, independently of the function being a template or not. Each translation unit will create its own version of the function and the linker will choose one to use (and, hopefully, throw away the other unused copies but whether it really does this depends on the linker and the object file format).

The interaction with templates comes in when looking at the various interactions between the template code and the functions it calls which may be templates themselves: When forcing the code not to be inlined, the compiler has no chance to avoid the overhead of a function call. Often the abstractions used by templates are very simple functions, e.g., "increment an iterator" and "dereference an iterator" mapping to underlying pointer operations, creation a function call can become rather expensive due to the function call overhead and the lost opportunity for optimizations. However, the compiler can actually see through this and do the right choices in many cases.

That said, I'm a big fan of creating explicit instantiations for certain templates. For example, removing certain parts of the IOStreams library from the headers and explicitly instantiating it in the library has a huge effect on compile time, especially when optimization is turned on: Calling a simple output function for an integer causes lots of templates to be instantiated. Putting this code into its own file and compiling it with the appropriate optimization options probably won't make much of a difference with respect to performance but it does have a major effect on compile times. This may have an indirect impact on performance, though: you can afford more iterations testing the performance of the code using the library.

Answer (score 0):

Even when you explicitly declare a function as `inline` there is no guarantee that C++ make it `inline`, so how you think that implementing a template all in header will force an `inline` implementation and cause you some problems?

In almost all cases you don't need second case although you can do like that but it is not needed to avoid `inline` problems